# ActiveRecord Primary Key - Auto increment

Tags: plugin-development

With Craft Active Record, using the definedAttributes Method how do I set my Primary Key Field to auto increment?

Or does it just calculate another number for the field that has not been used when the record gets saved?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 'column' in your defineAttributes:

e.g

```
'id_customer'       => array(AttributeType::Number, 'column' => ColumnType::PK)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to define an `id` attribute in your Craft Records Class - it is created automatically for you on plugin install as an auto-incremented int. You do need to define the id attribute on the equivalent Model though, and `AttributeType::Number` is fine for that.

Comment: thanks luke - my next question is, whats public function primaryKey() for, what if i needed to call my PK field id_customer and auto increment that?

Comment: why do you need to increment a non PK?

Comment: No I dont, I just dont want to be forced to call every PK field id.

Comment: no worries, its just a convention that works for most people. Out of interest, why do you prefer something other than id?

Comment: when I look at a table if I see something like customer_id in the customer_address table, I know its a join, it just makes sence to me :)

Comment: Hey Gary yes a foreign key to the customer table from the customer_address table makes sense as customer_id but why would you auto increment the foreign key?

Comment: say what? Im incrementing the primary key, using he reply from @Jay we have managed to change the primary key name from id to a name of our choice. :)

Comment: Quick note on this... if you've used defineRelations or defineIndexes then the automatic creation of an id Primary Key that auto_increments can be compromised. Always worth checking to see if this is the case.

Comment: I know this is an old issue, but I'm running into an error: `Field 'id' doesn't have a default value` when trying to save a custom record to the database. It seems the `id` field is not defined to `auto_increment`. I'm building a pair of models/records/migrations similar to the Commerce Cart + LineItem combo. Any thoughts @LukeHolder?